# Confusion about pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-address

I have a very basic but haunting problem about pointer and array:

```
int main() {

    int a[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int(*pa)[5] = &a;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;

    std::cout << pa << std::endl;   
    std::cout << (*pa) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, all four outputs give the same address, something like `'006AF784'`, which means `a == &a` and `pa == *pa`. This does not make any sense to me!

I understand of course `'a'` is the pointer to the first element while `'&a'` is the pointer to the whole array, so `'a+1'` is different from `'&a+1'`. But a variable is equal to its address and a pointer is equal to the content which points to is not understandable to me. I wonder what is exactly going on within C and compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit conversion and "arrays decaying into pointers" is behind this.

Let's draw this array. Assume that it's stored beginning at address 0x98.

```
 +———————————————————+
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
 +———————————————————+
 ^
 |
0x98
```

It should be clear that the address of the array is 0x98.
It's pretty clear that the address of its first element is also 0x98.

When you're printing

```
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

`a` is converted into a pointer to its first element – it is equivalent to

```
std::cout << &a[0] << std::endl;
```

As illustrated above, this has the same numeric value as the pointer to the array.

Likewise, when you print

```
std::cout << (*pa) << std::endl;
```

`*pa`, being an array, is converted into a pointer to its first element.

Comment: It's likely that variable 'a' should be think of as an object which contains 5 ints. So std::cout<<a is converted to count<<&a[0] to print the address of the first integer, and std::cout<<&a prints the address of the whole object which starts of course from its first element.

Comment: @Roy It's not only likely, it's a fact. That's what arrays are.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your own question. You want to know why `a`, `&a` are the same: the first expression designating the array evaluates to a pointer to the first element and the other evaluates to a pointer to the whole thing, as you note. But both are the same address: the first element is at the base address of the array. Then why is `pa` the same? Why, because you initialized it from `&a` in its declaration; it got its value from `&a`.  And `*pa` is the same because `pa` is a pointer to the array, so `*pa` is the array. But an array evaluates to a pointer to the first element: and you have already seen this with `a`. The expression `*pa` designates the same object as `a`, has the same type and evaluates the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that `a` isn't a pointer. In the semantics of C, the array name is convertible to a pointer, but is otherwise just an alias of the address of the first element of the array.

Then when it comes to `pa`, you're just saying that this pointer should be the address of `a`, so of course when you print it's value, it should be the same.
And of course since `*pa` is an array (its array name), it just aliases its first element's address - which is also `a`'s.

Comment: I think your first sentence is probably where the OP has the problem. `a` is an array variable, which, as you say, is convertible to a pointer, but simply holds the first element of the array is its value.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yes, `a` is an array variable. More precisely, `a` is the name of an array object. But `a` doesn't just hold the first element of the array; the value of `a` is the value of the entire array object, consisting of the values of all its elements. The *expression* `a` is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer expression, yielding the address of the array object's initial element.